# Toggle text of element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I toggle the text of an element with jQuery `.click()`, `.toggle()` and `.text()` only?

You can use a variable to hold the text to be toggled.

But please no classes to be turned off and on with .toggle().

Comment: Thank you for the answers, but I still haven't seen an answer with only `.click()`, `.toggle()` and `.text()`.  No use of if else statements please.  And no classes please.  If it's not possible, I understand.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to change the class of an element to change your css differennces. If you want to add text or additional elements. Look into the .append() function in jQuery.

However, just a personal opinion here, AngularJS would make that kind of stuff very easy to do. If you haven't learned any frameworks yet, I suggest you take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```js
var toggleText = "toggle",
  value;
$('div').click(function() {
  $(this).text(function(i, v) {
    if (v == toggleText)
      return value;
    else {
      value = v;
      return toggleText;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>hi.....</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.data()`

```
$(this).data('toggle', 0);           // initial data
$('div').click(function() {          // on click
  if($(this).data('toggle') === 0) { // if toggle is off
    $(this).data('toggle', 1);       // turn toggle on
  } else {                           // if toggle on
    $(this).data('toggle', 0);       // turn toggle off
  }
  $(this).append($(this).data('toggle'));
});
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9of5bz9v/)